# JS 'Firebase is not defined' error when trying to initialize

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am working with Glitch.com for my first ever IoT project (also no experience with front/back end). I set up this moisture plant sensor and added some code in Arduino. The moisture uploads from Arduino to a Firebase real-time database.

Now when trying to add this data from Firebase onto my webpage, I keep running into the same error. After multiple failed attempts myself, I decided to just remix an existing project for a Firebase connection. After filling in all my own Firebase info (auth, url ...) I still encountered the same issue, 'Firebase is not defined'. This error happens on these 3 rules;

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

```
var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref("Moisture");
```

The full code (for some context):

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>

    // Initialize Firebase
    // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
        apiKey: "your apiKey from firebase website",
        authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
      };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();


  // List to hold my moisture value
  var myMoisture = [];

  // Define database connection to correct branch, Moisture
  var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref("Moisture");

  // Function that acts when a 'new child is added to the DB' - i.e. new data is added this function runs.
  myDBConn.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey){

    // The data returned from the branch is put into a variable, dataPoint
    var dataPoint = data.val();

    // Convert the 'Temp' field from dataPoint into integers, then put them into the myTemps list
    myMoisture.push(parseInt(dataPoint.Temp));

    // Add all the Temps and get the total
    var totalT = 0;
    var i=0;
    for (i=0; i<myMoisture.length; i++){
      totalT += myMoisture[i];
    }

    // Create an average by dividing the sum of temps by the number of temps
    var average = totalT / myMoisture.length;

    // Update the page elements with the average and the last item (most recent) off the list 
    document.getElementById("averageT").innerHTML=average;
    document.getElementById("LiveT").innerHTML=myMoisture[myMoisture.length - 1];
  });
```

Another thing I was wondering is, what does datapoint.Temp mean? The original code was made for a webpage displaying live temperature and average temperature, however I want the moisture value. I still have to edit the code a bit, but want to make sure the Firebase connection works before I start on that.

Comment: You are using a very old version of the JS SDK. Current veriuosn is 7.11 `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"></script>`. Can you give a try with this import? Also note that loading the entire SDK is not efficient for production web apps, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize

Comment: Sadly that import gives the same errors. I've read through the article before, but I don't really understand it as I am very new to these subjects. Efficiency and security are not really relevant for my project, so I am okay with that. Hope you know something else I can try, thanks! :)

Comment: Is the code in your question the **EXACT** code? I mean, `var config=... myDBConn.on... ` shall be in a `script` tag. Is it the case?

Comment: This is the exact code. I tried adding <script> xx </script>, but it gives me an unexpected token var on this line: ```var dataPoint = data.val();```. Could you point out how and where to exactly add the script tag? When adding it, the error did in fact disappear, but this error came in it's place.

Comment: Have a look at the answer. If you encounter a new error, please add it to your question (i.e. edit the question).

Comment: The edit to this question invalidates the answer given, and thus must be rolled back. The advice from @RenaudTarnec perhaps was not clear enough - if fixing a problem reveals a new one then it is sometimes appropriate to add an addendum to the question so that readers already familiar with the problem can be asked for a bit more help. However this should be done sparingly - sometimes the new problem really is a separate issue, and should be asked separately.

Comment: I have rolled back the question to its earlier state. The edits you made [are in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60703044/revisions) - they are not lost. I would recommend asking a new question, since the new question looked like a complete question rewrite.

Comment: I appreciate it, I'll see if I get some suggestions on this question or can find something in the links Renaud Tarnec gave me before asking a new one. Don't want to spam the forums.

Comment: @Luukv19 Please ask a new question, as there isn't any detail in this one to understans what is this second problem. You apparently do the correct way (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events). So, create a new question with as much details as possible. Error details, screenshots of the debugger, etc...

Comment: Thanks all. @Luukv19, don't forget to accept Renaud's answer if you're happy it solves your first problem. There is a tick/check mark adjacent to the answer, which you can click if you are happy. It will turn green if you do so. It is not mandatory to do this, but it is a nice thank-you for your helper.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include your JavaScript code within a `script` tag as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
        apiKey: "your apiKey from firebase website",
        authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
      };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();


  // List to hold my moisture value
  var myMoisture = [];

  // Define database connection to correct branch, Moisture
  var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref("Moisture");

  // Function that acts when a 'new child is added to the DB' - i.e. new data is added this function runs.
  myDBConn.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey){

    // The data returned from the branch is put into a variable, dataPoint
    var dataPoint = data.val();

    // Convert the 'Temp' field from dataPoint into integers, then put them into the myTemps list
    myMoisture.push(parseInt(dataPoint.Temp));

    // Add all the Temps and get the total
    var totalT = 0;
    var i=0;
    for (i=0; i<myMoisture.length; i++){
      totalT += myMoisture[i];
    }

    // Create an average by dividing the sum of temps by the number of temps
    var average = totalT / myMoisture.length;

    // Update the page elements with the average and the last item (most recent) off the list 
    document.getElementById("averageT").innerHTML=average;
    document.getElementById("LiveT").innerHTML=myMoisture[myMoisture.length - 1];
  });

</script>
```

For more JavaScript details, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics and/or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @Luukv19  Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?